# How can I create a navigation view for iOS using Swift to swipe left and right through a set of images

Tags: ios, swiftui, swipe, gesture

I would like to create a navigation view for iOS using swift to scroll through a collection of images in a similar fashion to the Photo application on an iPhone. I believe that I need to create a UISwipeGestureRecognizer and add it to the View using addGestureRecognizer. The problem is View does not have a function addGestureRecognizer. UIView does but not View. Also are there any examples of how to do this? Most of the examples that I have seen are quite old and mention ViewControllers.
I am using Swift version 5.7.2 XCode version 14.2 and MACOS Ventura 13.1
Thanks in advance

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let leftSwipe: LeftSwipeRecognizer = LeftSwipeRecognizer()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "lizard")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear()
        {
            leftSwipe.direction = .left
            leftSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
            **self.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)**
        }
    }
}
```

the starred line gives the error

> Value of type 'ContentView' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'

Comment: You posted **SwiftUI** code... are you looking for SwiftUI help or Swift / UIKit help?

Comment: @DonMag: SwiftUI help :)

Comment: Head over to Google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swiftui image carousel` -- many, many examples, discussions, tutorials, etc.